# SQL Server Query: Problem with Performances with Where Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, where-clause

I have a "funny" issue with my query: this query use nested views inside but let's consider it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW
```

If I run this query, I have 5000 records in 18 seconds. 2300 with a field TYPE = 1 and 2700 with TYPE = 2.

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE TYPE = 1
```

I have 2300 records in 40 seconds (it could make sense).

BUT! If I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE TYPE = 2
```

The execution goes to infinite (I waited 5 hours and then I stopped it). How can it be possible? Do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us the view and index definitions etc, explain output.

Comment: Also let us know the size of the underlying table(s) involved in the view.

Comment: Without seeing the table & nested view definitions along with the queryplan we would just be guessing. If I were you I would remove the nested views and just write the query to access the tables directly.

Comment: Unfortunately query is not mine and I can't acess to it. I can only use them. In my opinion is very strange that a where condition works and the other not..

Comment: It's virtually impossible to diagnose the issue here without a query plan. The most likely cause is that in your last case the estimated number of rows for a step is going severely away from the actual.

Comment: are you literally executing query above or is there some kind of parametrization involved?

Comment: Is the query parameterized? It is normal for SQL Server to create a plan for a paremeterized query that works best for the value that was passed _first time_, that plan could be inefficient for other values. 5 hours is too much though, could be something else.

Comment: I solved the problem! I managed to change a Join condition in a smarter way and now eveything works fast! But I still don't know why this happened.
Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best approach but if you can't get a query plan out or modify the original view the following often helps (assuming you are able to create temporary tables).

```
SELECT * 
INTO #VIEW
FROM VIEW

SELECT *
FROM #VIEW
WHERE TYPE = 2
```

The issue is most likely caused by SQL Server making a very poor estimate on the number of rows coming through from part of the underlying queries. It's common issue when dealing with complex logic and one of the reasons that nesting views in views is often a bad idea. Dropping the results into a temporary table gives a break point where the number of rows involved becomes certain again.